# Cargar eventos Fullcalendar Laravel JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

estoy trabajando con fullcalendar y laravel, traigo los datos desde el contrador, ya que se muestran en la consola,pero no puedo hacer que se muestren en el calendario.
este es mi codigo:

routes.php

```
Route::get('events','EventsController@showEvents');
```

EventsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\model\eventsModel;

class EventsController extends Controller
{

    public function showEvents(){
        $events = eventsModel::all();
        return response()->json($events);
    }
}
```

index.blade.html

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        businessHours: {
          // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
          dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Monday - Thursday

          start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
          end: '19:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
        },

          editable: true,
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
          height: 500,
          slotMinutes: 15,
          loading: function(bool){
              if (bool) 
                  $('#loading').show();
              else 
                  $('#loading').hide();
          },

          minTime: '10:00',
          maxTime: '19:00',
          selectable: true,

          events: 
                $.ajax({

                       type:'get',
                       url:'events',
                       success: function (data)
                       {
                        console.log(data);
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                             events: data
                          });
                       }
                }),
```

no me genera ningun error, solo nose muestran los eventos.

por favor sugerencias
gracias

Answer (score 0):

No te los muestra por que no estás usando correctamente el ajax, que según la [documentación oficial](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) sería de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  businessHours: {
    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Monday - Thursday
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '19:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
  },
  editable: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  height: 500,
  slotMinutes: 15,
  loading: function(bool){
    if (bool) 
      $('#loading').show();
    else 
      $('#loading').hide();
  },
  minTime: '10:00',
  maxTime: '19:00',
  selectable: true,
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:'events',
      success: function (data){
        callback(data);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: gracias, pero puse el codigo como dices y ahora me sale: cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined